# What are "glyph names" in 'post' table of a .ttf font file used for?

Tags: fonts

I have some .otf font files. Unfortunately, it seems that .otf font files are not widely supported. So, I tried to convert them to .ttf font files, using otf2ttf (https://pypi.org/project/otf2ttf/). The conversion finished, but with a warning "Dropping glyph names, they do not fit in 'post' table."

What does this mean? What are the "glyph names" used for? Why do not the "glyph names" fit in 'post' table? Is there a way to make them fit in 'post' table?

After some research, it seems that, that warning means that the 'post' Format 3 is used (https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6post.html). It is said that "The printing behavior of this format on PostScript printers is unspecified, except that it should not result in a fatal or unrecoverable error. Some drivers may print nothing, other drivers may attempt to print using a default naming scheme." and that "Apple recommends against using 'post' table format 3 under most circumstances, as it can create problems with some printer drivers and PDF documents. The savings in disk space usually does not justify the potential loss in functionality." So, does this mean that, the .ttf font file that I got, may have problems when used for printing and creating PDF files?

Comment: "otf font files are not widely supported" — I'm not sure where you got that idea. .otf are widely supported nearly everywhere and have been for quite some time. There are some (ancient) applications that don't support them but generally you should be able to use a .otf anywhere you can use a .ttf.